# Sharepoint Designer and Foundation version mismatch error? 

Tags: sharepoint-designer, error

The company I am employed by has been running SharePoint 2010 successfully for several months now. Recently when anyone attempts to connect to our main site using SharePoint designer they are prevented from doing so an given the following error message: "Server Error: The version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation running on the server is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer you are using. You need a more recent version of SharePoint Designer". We are running the most recent version that we can find available for download from Microsoft. The server administrator has attempted to roll back the most recent patches / updates to SP Foundation, rebooted the site collection, tried a fresh install of Designer and other obvious common solutions to no avail.

This is the build of SPDesigner we're running: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d88a1505-849b-4587-b854-a7054ee28d66&displaylang=en

How do we resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this problem when a URL rewriter is used on the server (probably a bad idea in the first place). There are certain URLs that SharePoint Designer retrieves from the server and if it can't find them it gives this very misleading error message.

Here is a good diagnostic technique: start up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), and then start up SharePoint Designer and try to connect to your site. You will see lots of requests to the _vti_bin directory of your site. Note the HTTP traffic and see if any result in 404's or other unresolved HTTP errors. That will probably point you towards the problem.